# PHP string specialchars

Tags: php, string, curl, html-entities

I'm setting up a little webservice usable via an app on Android.
The function in the server is this:

```
 $lat=43.0552592;
 $lng=12.4483577;
 $radius=2000;

    $url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=italian&location=".$lat.",".$lng."&radius=".$raidus."&types=restaurant&sensor=false&key=".$apiKey;

    $urlW = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=italian&location=43.0552592,12.4483577&radius=2000&types=restaurant&sensor=false&key=XXXXxxxXXxxXXxxxxXXX";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    // Set so curl_exec returns the result instead of outputting it.
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    // Get the response and close the channel.
    $response = curl_exec($ch);

return $response;
```

The trouble is that if I query Google with the `$url` (as in the above example) it returns the JSON with `'INVALID REQUEST'`, but if the query at the first `curl_opt` is done with `$curlW` will works like a charm.
While debugging that I've discovered, making `$url` return, that gets every `&` converted (**before** the `curl_init`!) in `&amp`...!
So I've tried almost every PHP string function to force every & decode or replacing every *&entities* to *&* only without any result.
Any suggestion?

Comment: I suspect your method of debugging printed those encoded ampersands; can you use a simple `var_dump($url)` and have a look what it outputs? I suspect it isn't actually encoded as you describe

Comment: Why don't you use `http_build_query()`?

Comment: I can retrieve the answer only on the android logcat, dumping the webservice SOAP answer; when I return <code>$url</code> it gets the & _encoded_ instead of returning <code>$urlW</code> that doesn't gets "encoded", so I can assume that it's getting encoded for real.
@mpyw I'll give a try, I was hoping that a raw query were easier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you've done something wrong,

```
$url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=italian&location=".$lat.",".$lng."&radius=".$raidus."&types=restaurant&sensor=false&key=".$apiKey
```

should be

```
$url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=italian&location=".$lat.",".$lng."&radius=".$radius."&types=restaurant&sensor=false&key=".$apiKey;
```

but i don't guess that is what is doing the problem, try using `file_get_contents()` instead of curl, so $response will be like this:

```
$response = file_get_contents($url);
```

Comment: I don't get what's wrong with the <code>$url</code> var, maybe the **;** ?
I'll give a try with the <code>file_get_contents()</code>, thanks!

Comment: your are putting $raidus in $url ... thats a typo it must be $radius.

Comment: Shame on me D:
It was hidden in the query, I've now see that PHP was leaving that filed empty, it wasn't putting literally _$radius_ but was searching for a var "raidus"... I'm testing it but it's working now!